# Semi Structured to Structured Data

Tags: excel, vba

I need to transfer the data from Source sheet to Destination Sheet in column format.

Source sheet

[image: Source Sheet]

Destination sheet

[image: Destination Sheet]

```
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Invoice As Long
Dim Item As Long
Dim Qty As Long

Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For Counter = 1 To Lastrow
If Sheet1.Cells(Counter,1).Value = "Product:" Then
  Sheet1.Cells(Counter,2).Copy
  Sheet2.Activate
  Item = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  Sheet2.Cells(Item,2).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Sheet1.Activate
ElseIf Left(Sheet1.Cells(Counter,1).Value,3) = "INV" Then
  Sheet1.Cells(Counter,1).Copy
  Sheet2.Activate
  Invoice = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  Sheet2.Cells(Invoice,1).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Sheet1.Activate
  Sheet1.Cells(Counter,2).Copy
  Sheet2.Activate
  Qty = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  Sheet2.Cells(Qty,3).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Sheet1.Activate
End If
Next Counter
```

I am struggling with the Item Column. I can't seem to get it working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Suggest you post your data as text, not a picture eg using [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerQuery:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type any}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Item", each if [Column1]="Item:" then [Column2] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Item"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each Text.StartsWith([Column1], "INV")),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Column1", "Item", "Column2"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Column1", "Inv Nr"}, {"Column2", "Qty"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]